# How to save an object with a list as attribute in a SQL Database

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

I want to store a list of Day objects in my sqflite database.
The Day class looks like this:

```
class Day {
  String date; 
  List<DoneTask> doneTasks;
  double score = 0;

Day({this.doneTasks, this.date});
}
```

the DoneTask class:

```
class DoneTask {
  Category category;
  double score;
  String description;

DoneTask({this.category, this.score, this.description});
}
```

Category has an attribute id, which is all I want to store from that.

I'm not sure how I can realize that with sqflite.
I was thinking about adding the Attribute `String day` to the DoneTasks class for loading the DoneTasks in first, and sort them into the Days later. But this does not sound like a good solution for me, has anyone an idea how I could do it in a better way?

I'm very new to using SQL, so id appreciate simple answers/

(this is what I used yet for sqflite: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)

Comment: There is really a lot to good database design. You would be better served reading a book about it, it's really to much for a single helpful explanation here.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend going with a noSQL database if that is the data architecture you are going for. Of course, I do not know the scope of your entire project thus it is possible that an SQL database is a better fit for some reason that is unknown to me. But given just what you have presented, a noSQL alternative to sqflite seems like a better option. This would allow records to be stored effectively as objects, allowing you to store objects within objects, rather than having to create a bunch of tables cross referencing one another. It just seems more intuitive to me to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would save it :

- First create a table to save your `Day` object. Inside it you will save only the `date` and `score` properties.

The method `Database().insert` return a `Future<int>` which is the id of the newly created row so you can use it to save your `DoneTask` and link them to the `Day`.

- Now, you can save each of your `List<DoneTask>` in another table with a column `id_day` as their identifier.

Here is a modelization of what it could look.
[image]